# Find a matrix whose columns forms the basis for the given subspace.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, matrix-equations

Let  $a\in \mathbb{R}^n$ be a nonzero vector and let $S=\{\mathbf{u:a^{t}u=0}\}$ Show that S is a subspace. What is the dimension of S? Find a matrix **A** whose
columns form a basis of S. In particular, do this exercise for
$\mathbf a=(1,-1,1)^{t}$.

Can anyone give me hint to complete my solution, what is the matrix **A** and what is the purpose of considering a single point **a** in $\mathbb{R}^3 $ in the end of the question?

**My try**:

Since  $S=\{\mathbf{u:a^{t}u=0}\}$

$\Rightarrow \mathbf{a^{t}u=0}$

$\Rightarrow \mathbf{a_1u_1 +a_2u+a_3u_3+...+a_nu_n=0}$

Since **a** is the non zero vector so I think the only solution for above equation is that all $\mathbf{u_i =0 }$.
Hence the set  $S=\{\mathbf{0}\}$. And it is subspace(we can prove it).
So the basis of the $S \ is \ \{\mathbf{}\}$ and the dimension of **S** is the **0**.
**What will be the possible answers of the remaining questions?**

Comment: no, you are wrong. do you know https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouch%C3%A9%E2%80%93Capelli_theorem ?

Comment: Start with a simple case. Take $a=(1,0,\ldots,0)$. Then all the vectors $(0,x_2,x_3,...)$ are in $S$. Of course a base in this case could be $e_2,e_3,.., e_n$

Comment: Hint: Choose, e.g., $u_1 = a_2$ and $u_2 = -a_1$ and $u_3 = \ldots = u_n = 0$.

Comment: Hint: $S$ is the nullspace of the linear map $u\mapsto a^tu.$

Comment: You’re misapplying the definition of linear independence. The $a_i$ and $u_i$ are **scalars**. If anything, your conclusion should be the opposite: if $n\gt1$, then there _must_ be a nontrivial solution to the equation.